# Cefsharp download window for showing progress in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, download, cefsharp

I am creating a browser using Cefsharp in VB.Net, and I have been trying to create a download window that shows the progress of the current download. I don't know if I am doing something wrong or if it is the way CEF works, but I put in a download handler by adding `browser.DownloadHandler = New DownloadHandler` to `Form1_Load` and creating a new class like this (with `downloading` being the form I created for showing the progress):

```
Public Class DownloadHandler
Implements IDownloadHandler
Public Function OnBeforeDownload(downloadItem As DownloadItem, ByRef downloadPath As String, ByRef showDialog As Boolean) As Boolean Implements IDownloadHandler.OnBeforeDownload
    downloadPath = downloadItem.SuggestedFileName
    showDialog = True
    downloading.Show()

    Return True
End Function

Public Function OnDownloadUpdated1(downloadItem As DownloadItem) As Boolean Implements IDownloadHandler.OnDownloadUpdated
    My.Settings.downloadpercent = downloadItem.PercentComplete.ToString

    Return False
End Function 
End Class
```

On the `downloading` form I have this code for showing the progress:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim percentcomplete As Integer = My.Settings.downloadpercent * 5
    Me.PictureBox1.Size = New Size(percentcomplete, 25)
End Sub

Private Sub downloading_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

This may not be the best way to show a `ProgressBar`, but I have a picture box that just has a green bar, and the total width of the form is 500px. The code is telling it to read the `PercentComplete` setting put in `My.Settings.downloadpercent`, multiply it by 5, so when the progress in 100%, it will go across the whole form.

The problem is that the ProgressBar is not being updated to show the current progress. It goes a little bit, but then it just stops. Am I doing something wrong, or is `OnDownloadUpdated` not a good place to put that? Any suggestions of how to fix this?

***Edit:***

I am using `CefSharp 39.0.0-pre03`. Also, when the save file dialog comes up, no matter if you click Save or Cancel, the browser always triggers a `LoadError`, so it loads the custom HTML error page I made, and since it requires a URL for loading HTML, I put in "http://rendering/"... So I guess that would be a domain change. That issue (in the comments) could be the problem, but then we also need to figure out why it is triggering a `LoadError`.

Comment: What version of `CefSharp` are you using? There is an open issue that relates to downloads, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/595 maybe unrelated. Are you navigating away before the download completes?

Comment: Might be better to open a github issue to discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that may be of interest to those who faced the same or similar problem:

1. Declare `Public` your `Picturebox`, in a module:

   ```
   Module Module1
       Public PictureBox1 As New PictureBox
   End Module
   ```
2. In `MainForm` you can declare the attributes you want (after the InitializeComponent). Example:

   ```
   With PictureBox1
       .BorderStyle = Border3DStyle.Flat
       .Image = Bitmap.FromFile(YourImageFileName)
       '......
   End With
   ```
3. In the `DownloadHandler` Class:

   ```
   Public Function OnDownloadUpdated1(downloadItem As DownloadItem) As Boolean 
    Implements IDownloadHandler.OnDownloadUpdated
      Dim percentcomplete As Integer=downloadItem.PercentComplete * 5
       PictureBox1.Size = New Size(percentcomplete, 25)
       Return False
   End Function
   ```